# How can I install miniconda to be accessible to all users?

Tags: root, anaconda, multi-user

I am trying to install [miniconda](https://docs.anaconda.com/free/miniconda/) as root to be accessible to all user in a virtual machine.

My goal is to share a virtual environment between multiple users.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How and where to install conda to be accessible to all users](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1457726/how-and-where-to-install-conda-to-be-accessible-to-all-users)

Comment: @JohnCarter thanks a lot, I had read that answer but the procedure is different, eventually yesterday I solved it this way..

Comment: I am happy you found a solution!

Answer (score 1):

I have used this solution so far, for installing miniconda to `/opt`.

As root:

```
cd /opt
mkdir -p miniconda3
wget https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -O /opt/miniconda3/miniconda.sh
bash /opt/miniconda3/miniconda.sh -b -u -p /opt/miniconda3
rm -rf /opt/miniconda3/miniconda.sh
```

Then I logged in as the non-root user:

```
./opt/miniconda3/bin/conda init
```

Restart the shell.